# fatal error: Index out of range (Swift 3)

Tags: swift3

I want to make an application that you would prefer, but it gets error when I click a button, the app quits and it gets this fatal error error: Index out of range. How do I fix this error? This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var legendaAzul: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var legendaVermelho: UILabel!

@IBAction func botaoAzul(_ sender: Any) {

    var resultadoAzul: [String] = []
    let numero1 = arc4random_uniform( 6 )

    resultadoAzul.append("Mata uma pessoa")
    resultadoAzul.append("Come um humano")
    resultadoAzul.append("Ser rico, mas morre daqui a um mes")
    resultadoAzul.append("Ser amigo do Homem - Aranha")
    resultadoAzul.append("Servir 7 anos em uma prisão violenta")

    legendaAzul.text = resultadoAzul [(Int(numero1))]
}

@IBAction func botaoVermelho(_ sender: Any) {

    var resultadoVermelho: [String] = []
    let numero2 = arc4random_uniform( 6 )

    resultadoVermelho.append("Mata você mesmo")
    resultadoVermelho.append("Come qualquer coisa")
    resultadoVermelho.append("Ser pobre, mas vive para sempre")
    resultadoVermelho.append("Ser amigo do Homem - Formiga")
    resultadoVermelho.append("Matar e comer seu cachorro")

    legendaVermelho.text = resultadoVermelho [(Int(numero2))]
}
```

Comment: Have you check the stack trace or debug it to find where the error happens?

Comment: The maximum number `arc4random_uniform(6)` can generate is 5 – the maximum index of your arrays is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you hard coded the random's max value, and it's too high. You should be obtaining it dynamically from the arrays' `count`. Also, there's no reason to be doing repeated `append(_:)` of static data. Just use an array literal.

```
@IBOutlet weak var legendaAzul: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var legendaVermelho: UILabel!

let resultadoAzul = ["Mata uma pessoa",
    "Come um humano",
    "Ser rico, mas morre daqui a um mes",
    "Ser amigo do Homem - Aranha",
    "Servir 7 anos em uma prisão violenta"
]

@IBAction func botaoAzul(_ sender: Any) {
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(resultadoAzul.count))
    legendaAzul.text = resultadoAzul[index]
}


let resultadoVermelho = [
    "Mata você mesmo",
    "Come qualquer coisa",
    "Ser pobre, mas vive para sempre",
    "Ser amigo do Homem - Formiga",
    "Matar e comer seu cachorro"
]

@IBAction func botaoVermelho(_ sender: Any) {
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(resultadoVermelho.count))
    legendaVermelho.text = resultadoVermelho[index]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is my first app made by me and thanks for helping me !!